# position two components as columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a screen that looks like this:

[image]

The text is at the top while the red section (VideoComponent) is at the bottom. I want the VideoComponent to appear on the left side while all the text should move towards the right. Like a flex box. Or like in 2 columns.

```
    return (
        <div>
            <main className="content">
   <div className="text">
                In this section.....TEXT
<div className="video">
                    <VideoComponent />
                </div>
 </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
```

I tried adding float right/left to the css but it does not make a difference.

```
.content{
    padding-left: 280px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background-color: white;

}

.buttons{
    padding-top: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
}

.heading{
    font-size: 25px;
}

.text{
    float: left;
}


.video{
    float: right;
}
```

How else can I fix this? Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-turing-tulc2?file=/src/VideoComponent.tsx

Comment: Like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-fire-vkjso

Answer (score 1):

You could use Flexbox to achieve this. I know you're working with react, but this is just HTML and CSS. Maybe try something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    My text
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="imageurl">
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display:flex
}
.text {
  margin: 10px
}
```

https://codepen.io/pauladiniz/pen/abpxeLK

Comment: I wanted the text to be on the right and video to be on the left of the screen, opposite to what you did. Also my text is quite large so it goes to multiple lines. In that case, it wouldn't work. Maybe you could try on the codesandbox link I shared

Comment: I swear it works the same way. If you want the video on the left, then your first div inside the wrapper div should contain the video and above this div, the other one with the text. I edited my codepen. Also, you should use <p> on your text, since it's long.

https://codepen.io/pauladiniz/pen/abpxeLK

Answer (score 0):

Set the "text" class in the css file to "display: flex;" this should automatically change the objects (the text and the video) to a row. Maybe float will cancel it out but i am not sure about that. Just try it out.

Comment: If I do this, the first para, the heading, and the third para all come as separate columns while the video component is still at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't nested your elements properly.. your JSX should be like this below

```
<div>
  <main className="content">
    <div className="video">
        <VideoComponent />
      </div>
    <div className="text">
      In this section.....TEXT
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Simply update with the below **css**.

```
    .content{
        padding-left: 280px;
        padding-top: 100px;
        background-color: white;
        display:flex;
    
    }
    
    .buttons{
        padding-top: 20px;
        flex-direction: column;
        display: flex;
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    .heading{
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    .text{
        // float: left;
    }
    
    
    .video{
        // float: right;
    }
```

This problem will be reolved

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is very simple that you can use cross-browser too.

```
<main>
   <div class="text">text goes here</div>
   <div class="video">video here</div>
</main>
```

Now for the CSS part, you can do this

```
main{
  display:flex;
}

main .text{
    order:2;
}

main .video{
     order:1;
}
```

and you can test it on cross-browser we have another CSS property too which is already used by ''Medi'' flex-direction but it does not support Firefox, So you can use "order" which is supported in all browsers.